# Convert API Reponse to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, urllib

I making an API call with the following code:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, body, headers)

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    json_obj = json.loads(string)
```

Which returns the following:

```
{"forecast": [17.588294043898163, 17.412641963452206], 
    "index": [
            {"SaleDate": 1629417600000, "Type": "Type 1"}, 
            {"SaleDate": 1629504000000, "Type": "Type 2"}
        ]
}
```

How can I convert this api response to a Panda DataFrame to convert the dict in the following format in pandas dataframe

```
Forecast                 SaleDate     Type
17.588294043898163       2021-08-16   Type 1
17.412641963452206       2021-08-17   Type 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.json_normalize`?

Comment: @gofvonx I am very new to Pandas and learning it, I am googling what you have suggested lets see if I can get it to work :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. It uses `pandas.Series` to convert the dictionary to columns and `pandas.to_datetime` to map the correct date from the millisecond timestamp:

```
d = {"forecast": [17.588294043898163, 17.412641963452206], 
    "index": [
            {"SaleDate": 1629417600000, "Type": "Type 1"}, 
            {"SaleDate": 1629504000000, "Type": "Type 2"}
        ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.concat([df['forecast'], df['index'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df['SaleDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SaleDate'], unit='ms')
```

output:

```
    forecast   SaleDate    Type
0  17.588294 2021-08-20  Type 1
1  17.412642 2021-08-21  Type 2
```

Comment: My opinion - solution good for small data, else rather dont use it. There are 2 bottlenecks - `pd.concat` and `.apply(pd.Series)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can give it a try, using `list comprehension` to flatten the data.

```
import pandas as pd

flatten = [
    {"forecast": j, **resp['index'][i]} for i, j in enumerate(resp['forecast'])
]

pd.DataFrame(flatten)
```

---

```
    forecast       SaleDate    Type
0  17.588294  1629417600000  Type 1
1  17.412642  1629504000000  Type 2
```